# backbone.js cannot render a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Below I have the code for one of my modules. This is kind of spagetti-ish code, but all I want to accomplish is having a model, a collection, and render a view (using underscore templates) connecting the data from the collection to the views. I'm failing miserably. The problem I'm getting is that trying to run the last call down there to testfeed.render() tells me that render is not a function, yet it is clearly defined. I'm able to fetch that data and seemingly add it to the collection from the api. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 // Create a new module.
  var Tagfeed = app.module();

  // Default model.
  Tagfeed.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        image : ''
    },
    initialize : function(){
        console.log('tagfeed model is initialized');
        this.on("change", function(){
            console.log("An attribute has been changed");
        });
    }
  });

  var feedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tagfeed.Model,
    initialize : function () {
        console.log('feedcollection is initialized');
    },
    fetch: function () {
        var thisCollection = this;
        Api_get('/api/test', function(data){

            $.each(data.data, function(){
                thisCollection.add(this);
            });
            return thisCollection;
        })
    }
  });

  var test = new Tagfeed.Model({name:'test'});

  var newFeedCollection = new feedCollection();

  newFeedCollection.fetch();

  console.log(newFeedCollection.at(0));

  var testfeed = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#main'),
    collection : newFeedCollection,
    render: function( event ){
        var compiled_template = _.template( $("#tag-template").html() );
        this.$el.html( compiled_template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this; //recommended as this enables calls to be chained.
    }
  });

  testfeed.render();
```

EDIT ******* updated code from @mu is short suggestions

```
  // Create a new module.
  var Tagfeed = app.module();

  // Default model.
  var tagModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        image : '',
        pins : 0,
        repins : 0,
        impressions : 0
    },
    initialize : function(){
        console.log('tagfeed model is initialized');
        this.on("change", function(){
            console.log("An attribute has been changed");
        });
    }
  });

  var feedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: tagModel,
    initialize : function () {
        console.log('feedcollection is initialized');
    },
    fetch: function () {
        var thisCollection = this;

        Api_get('/reporting/adlift/pin_details', function(data){

            thisCollection.add(data.data);

            return data.data;
        })
    }
  });

  var test = new tagModel({name:'test'});

  var newFeedCollection = new feedCollection();

  newFeedCollection.fetch();

  console.log(newFeedCollection.at(0));

  var TestFeed = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#main'),
    render: function( event ){
        console.log('here');
        var compiled_template = _.template( $("#tag-template").html(), this.collection.toJSON());
        this.el.html( compiled_template );
        return this; //recommended as this enables calls to be chained.
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('initialize view');
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    }
  });

  //Tagfeed.testfeed.prototype.render();

  var testfeed = new TestFeed({ collection: newFeedCollection });

  testfeed.render();
```

and now when i run testfeed.render() I don't see any error, nor do i see that console.log in the render function. thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
var testfeed = Backbone.View.extend({ /*...*/ });
testfeed.render();
```

That makes your `testfeed` a view "class", you have to create a new instance with `new` before you can render it:

```
var TestFeed = Backbone.View.extend({ /*...*/ });
var testfeed = new TestFeed();
testfeed.render();
```

You're also doing this inside the "class":

```
collection : newFeedCollection
```

That will attach `newFeedCollection` to each instance of that view and that might cause some surprising behavior. The usual way of getting a collection into a view is pass it to the constructor:

```
var TestFeed = Backbone.View.extend({ /* As usual but not collection in here... */ });
var testfeed = new TestFeed({ collection: newFeedCollection });
testfeed.render();
```

The [view constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor) will automatically set the view's `this.collection` to the collection you pass when building the view.

Another thing to consider is that this:

```
newFeedCollection.fetch();
```

is usually an AJAX call so you might not have anything in your collection when you try to render it. I would do two things to deal with this:

1. Your view's `render` should be able to deal with an empty collection. This mostly depends on your template being smart enough to be sensible when the collection is empty.
2. Bind `render` to the collection's `"reset"` event in the view's `initialize`:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
   }
   ```

Another problem you'll have is that your view's `render` is trying to render `this.model`:

```
this.$el.html( compiled_template(this.model.toJSON()) );
```

when your view is based on a collection; you want to change that to:

```
this.$el.html(compiled_template({ tags: this.collection.toJSON() }));
```

You'll need the `tags` in there so that the template has a name to refer to when looking at the collection data.

Also, you should be able to replace this:

```
$.each(data.data, function(){
    thisCollection.add(this);
});
```

with just this:

```
thisCollection.add(data.data);
```

There's no need to add them one by one, [`Collection#add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) is perfectly happy with an array of models.

And here's a demo with (hopefully) everything sorted out:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WXddy/

I had to fake the `fetch` internals but everything else should be there.

Comment: ok thanks so much for the information, that makes things alot clearer. however, now when I call on testfeed.render() I see no error, but nothing happens and it doesnt seem to call on the render function. any thoughts why that might be?

Comment: If you're not getting an error, the `render()` is probably running. Just not the way you thought. :-) You can check whether the `render()` did what you thought it should have done by checking your `view.el` after you've `render()` the view. E.g. `console.log(view.render().el)` My guess from left field is that while it is rendering, the `el` isn't being attached to the DOM in a place where you'd expect to see it.

Comment: well if i actually put a console.log inside that render function which I'm expecting to be called, it doesn't output anything. I can't put a breakpoint or anything on it either

Comment: So your `console.log` in the render doesn't get called? Maybe you can add an update to your question with the most recent code.

Comment: @Even: Are you doing `this.el.html(...)` or `this.$el.html(...)`?

Comment: @muistooshort : Noticed that too but that would give an error "has no method 'html'"...

Comment: i used this.el.html because it said this.$el was undefined or smoethin

Comment: now neither of them work because render isnt getting called for some reason :P

Comment: You define el as `$('#main')`, is that element ready to go and already present when you instantiate and call `render()`?

Comment: yeah its in my index.html file. again though, its not even getting to that point to try and deal with everything in render

Comment: weird, if i change the function name and call to render2 then it works fine

Comment: Here's an thought. It doesn't seem to be the most likely that just changing the name of the function would make it work. So is it possible that it is working some of the time and not all the time? (You mentioned that `render()` worked before) I noticed from another post of yours that you're using (it seems) require.js. I see a lot of require.js problems that happen sporadically due to mistakes in correctly taking into account the async nature of AMD modules. Could that be the reason why sometimes the code gets called and sometimes it seems... not at all? That's the best I got. :-P

Comment: @Evan: I missed a mistake in the template handling, you need to say `{tags: this.collection.toJSON()}` and then use `tags` in your template. Sorry about that. Also make sure everything gets loaded in the right order, you don't want to look at anything in the DOM until it has been loaded, a `$(function() { .. });` wrapper can be used for that. Anyway, have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WXddy/

Answer (score 1):

`testfeed` is not an instance - it's a constructor function.

```
var instance = new testfeed(); 
instance.render();
```

would probably work (what with you defining `el` during View **definition** - making it a prototype property, IIRC).